How to download files in flutter using pocketbase across all the platforms?
I am trying include the download files option in my flutter app. I am using pocketbase to store the files and cubit for my state management. How can I implement this so that it works on all the platforms.
I managed to implement it on web, but I want to make it compatible for other platform. In addition I just implemented it with two files by declaring them as a list. I would like to know how we can implement it dynamically when there are large number of files.

The documentation seems to have Dart examples that should work across all platforms: https://pocketbase.io/docs/files-handling/.
If you tried something based on that and it doesn't work, please edit your question to show what you tried, and how it failed (read the link please, it's quite useful).
